# Rjags Error: Node inconsistent with parents (Error in node n.pos[4])

Tags: r, function, rjags

[the dataframe has four datapoints, and I wanted calculate different lambdas for each datapoint.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLDgo.png)
(You can see the captured picture when you click the sentence above).
[this is the model I want to specify.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp9NN.png)

I have specified my model and put that model and data into the jags.model, but I got an error message that says "Node inconsistent with parents" which I don't know the reason.
What would be the possible underlying reason behind this and how to solve this?

```
 jcode <- "model{ 
for (i in 1:1){
n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
seropos_est[i] = 1-exp(-10*lambda_1*age[i]) #catalytic model
}
for (i in 2:2){
n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
seropos_est[i] = 1-exp(-20*lambda_1*age[i] - 10*lambda_2*age[i]) #catalytic model
}
for (i in 3:3){
n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
seropos_est[i] = 1-exp(-20*lambda_1*age[i] - 20*lambda_2*age[i] - 10*lambda_3*age[i]) #catalytic model
}
for (i in 4:4){
    n.pos[i] ~ dbinom(seropos_est[i],N[i]) #fit to binomial data
seropos_est[i] = 1-exp(-20*lambda_1*age[i] - 20*lambda_2*age[i] - 20*lambda_3*age[i] - 10*lambda_4*age[i]) #catalytic model
    }


#  prior dists
  lambda_1 ~ dunif(0,1) #uninformative prior
  lambda_2 ~ dunif(0,1) #uninformative prior
  lambda_3 ~ dunif(0,1) #uninformative prior
  lambda_4 ~ dunif(0,1) #uninformative prior
}"

    mcmc.length=50000
jdat = list(n.pos= df_chik$N.pos,
            N=df_chik$N,
            age=df_chik$agemid)
jmod = jags.model(textConnection(jcode), data=jdat, n.chains=1, n.adapt = 15000)
```

Comment: You appear to be attempting to fit four different models to the first four data points in your data (and ignoring the remainder of ther data points.  I doubt very much that is what you *want to do.  Some context might be helpful...

Comment: yes, exactly. i was trying to estimate different lambdas for each line of the dataset and that is why i am treating each data point separately. I will add sample dataframe here!

Comment: My answer to your question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275612 also applies to this question